# Restriction of a fibration to an open subset with diffeomorphic fibers

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $p:E\to B$ be a locally trivial fibration of connected, non-compact smooth manifolds. Let $U\subset E$ be a connected open subset and $p|_U:U\to p(U)$ has diffeomorphic fibers.

Can we conclude that $p|_U$ is again a locally trivial fibration?

This question is related to my other question I posted before, but I find this general version interesting in its own right.

Comment: It's probably best to accept Idrissi's answer as it did answer your question, at the time.  You could then open a new question.  Generally speaking its frowned upon to change a question after answers start appearing.  Ideally questions are not edited at all.

Comment: Ryan, if someone can edit his/her wrong answer then a question also can be edited for the discussion to continue in the desired direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the answer is no. **OP added after I answered the requirement that the fibers have to be connected.**

Let $S^1 = \mathbb{R} \cup {\infty}$. The projection on the first coordinate $S^1 \times \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ is a locally trivial fibration of connected non-compact smooth manifolds. But the restriction to the following open subset of $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$:

[image]

has diffeomorphic fibers (they're all diffeomorphic to $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$) but it isn't a locally trivial fibration. Here the green part is glued with the green part, the red with the red.

Comment: @OP. I'm not going to try hitting a moving target.